# What happened to HtmlHelper's 'ViewContext.Controller'?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, html-helper

In my old ASP.NET web app, I coded an HTML helper to get access to the context of the controller executing the current view by accessing `ViewContext.Controller`:

```
public static string GetControllerString(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper) {
    string controllerString = htmlHelper.ViewContext.Controller.ToString();
    return ".NET Controller: " + controllerString;
}
```

However, this no longer seems to exist in ASP.NET Core's HTML helper object:

```
public static string GetControllerString(this IHtmlHelper htmlHelper) {
    string controllerString = htmlHelper.ViewContext.Controller.ToString(); // Doesn't exist!
    return ".NET Core Controller: " + controllerString;
}
```

What happened to `ViewContext.Controller`?  Is it now impossible to get hold of the controller context from the HTML helper object?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They've changed inheritance chain and terminology a bit. So, `ViewContext` in ASPNET Core doesn't inherit from `ControllerContext`, like in the older ASPNET MVC [framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.viewcontext?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2).

Instead, `ViewContext` [inherits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.rendering.viewcontext?view=aspnetcore-2.2) from `ActionContext` which is more generic term.

Due to that fact, there is no inherited `Controller` property on the `ViewContext` object, but rather you can use `ActionDescriptor` [property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.abstractions.actiondescriptor?view=aspnetcore-2.2), to get the needed value.

```
public static string GetControllerString(this IHtmlHelper htmlHelper) {
    string actionDescriptor = htmlHelper.ViewContext.ActionDescriptor.DisplayName;
    return ".NET Core Controller: " + actionDescriptorName;
}
```

Comment: As an additional note, the `ActionDescriptor` can be either a `ControllerActionDescriptor`, for the classic controller-style of rendering MVC views, or a `PageActionDescriptor`, for the new so-called "Razor pages" method of building pages.  They have quite different properties.