# What replaced Viewcontext.Controller in ASP.net core 3

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

in ASP.Net, you were able to get from `ViewContext` the controller and have access to its properties by using `ViewContext.Controller`. Now in ASP.Net Core, `ViewContext` does not inherit from  `ControllerContext`  [as said here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57725757/what-happened-to-htmlhelpers-viewcontext-controller). I have properties inside that controller that are called inside a shared layout (that is of course shared across all my apps and can't have model for obvious reason) and I was wondering what replaced it or how can I get the current context controller object.

I know you can get the name of the controller and the action by using the `DisplayName` propety from  `ViewContext.ActionDescriptor` but that's not what I'm looking for.

Do I now need to use a static class to get my properties or is there another way similar to what `ViewContext.Controller` do in older version of ASP.Net?

Thanks alot !

Comment: Your view shouldn't have access to your controller it's antipattern to MVC instead it should  communicate with controller by request and response.

Comment: That's what I thought. I'll figure something else. Thanks ! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can get controller name by `ViewContext.RouteData`.

```
 public static string GetControllerString(this IHtmlHelper htmlHelper)
        {
           
            string controllerString = htmlHelper.ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();
            return ".NET Core Controller: " + controllerString;
        }
```